# Merge [progress-database] into [progress-db]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

I suggest that question tagged [progress-database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/progress-database) **x 12** are retagged
[progress-db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/progress-db) **x 69**. The subject is exactly the same so there's no need to have two different tags.

Comment: They even have the same description.

Answer (score 1):

This is done--there are no more questions tagged [progress-database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/progress-database), and it now redirects to [progress-db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/progress-db).

[image]

Comment: @Payeli [progress-db] is more common, so I removed less common tag.

Comment: @Payeli I was attracted here as nicael performed the retag and I... *shudder* searched. Ummm, while I'm not in the progress community any more, I can still safely say "progress-db" will be much more popular with them than "progress-database".